# Internet stops working after a few minutes (13.04)

Tags: networking

Seemingly at random, my internet stops working on Ubuntu 13.04. Specifically, wired and wireless show as connected, but I cannot reach any page using any web browser or get a ping response.

I can sometimes get a few minutes of internet access when I reboot, although whether or not this happens also appears to be at random. It always disappears, although still shows as being connected, after no more than 5 minutes though.

I've isolated the problem to Ubuntu itself:

- No issue on Windows 7
- Issue persists on Unity, Cinnamon desktop, Gnome desktop
- Issue persists with multiple networks

I've also tried `sudo dhclient wlan0` as recommended in a similar thread, with no luck after rebooting.

I'm unsure of what the issue could be, because it worked previously with no issues on 12.10 and 13.04, and I can't isolate any action that caused it.

If anybody has any ideas, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Check the network routing before and after you see this via `netstat -r`.  Check the status of the ethernet ports via `ifconfig` before and after.  Can you ping a specific IP number and not the name?  Then check `/etc/resolv.conf` before and after.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're satisfied with a wired connection, turn off wireless, unplug the network cable and plug it back in when the notification icon reads that you are disconnected.

I don't know why both don't work at the same time in the 3.8 kernels, but this works for me on my Lenovo laptop.

Follow up: 14 June 2013 - I re-enabled WIFI and unplugged my network cable. So far it's working fine.

Having the two on together seems to be the issue in the 3.8 kernels. I still have a 3.5 kernel that doesn't have any problem running both simultaneously.

Comment: Accepted this, seems to have worked. Wired is sufficient for me usually, and hopefully wireless will work fine if I turn wired off. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue on 13.04. My motherboard has 2 network cards and both are connected to the router over the wires.

This is what helped me:

```
 sudo apt-get remove network-manager*
```

This will remove the network manager that you can access on a top-right corner from the Unity UI. But it actually made my connection work and it is not dropping pings anymore.

Good luck.